# Groovy's Path.traverse() extension, IntelliJ idea syntactic error

Tags: groovy

I am editing a Groovy (3.0.10) script and I am getting a syntactic error that I do not understand:

[image]

When I try this in GroovyConsole, it seems to work just fine.

Why is IntelliJ IDEA complaining? This is with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1.

The snippet in text:

```
final java.nio.file.Path p;
p.traverse(type: FileType.FILES, nameFilter: ~/^\.deployment$/, maxDepth: 1) { final Path dotDeploymentPath ->
    println dotDeploymentPath
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I actually got the same error from Groovy when running the script in our product:

```
Script4.groovy: 59: [Static type checking] - Cannot call java.nio.file.Path#traverse(java.util.Map <java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>, groovy.lang.Closure) with arguments [java.util.LinkedHashMap <java.lang.String, java.io.Serializable>, groovy.lang.Closure]
 @ line 59, column 9.
           extensionsPath.traverse(type: FileType.FILES, nameFilter: ~/^\.deployment$/, maxDepth: 1) { final Path dotDeploymentPath ->
           ^
```

**UPDATE 2**

I ended up with this which seems to work just fine. I still don't understand why Groovy does not like the options as arguments of the call.

```
def final traverseOptions = [type: FileType.FILES, nameFilter: ~/^\.deployment$/, maxDepth: 1] as Map<String, Object>;
extensionsPath.traverse(traverseOptions) { final Path dotDeploymentPath ->
```

Comment: I don't see errors with provided code on my side. Do you use any custom plugins?

Comment: @y.bedrov I am not aware of any custom Groovy related plugins in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Comment: @y.bedrov I don't think this is IntelliJ IDEA problem after all. I am removing the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out. The issue was that I used `@CompileStatic` at the top of my class. I used `@CompileStatic` because I misunderstood what it does. I thought it were similar to saying `static class` in Java. But that is not what it does. What it does instead is this, from the [docs](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/transform/CompileStatic.html): *This will let the Groovy compiler use compile time checks in the style of Java then perform static compilation, thus bypassing the Groovy meta object protocol.*

(This shows how important it is to provide self contained test case. I should have known better.)